# Add properties to getter-annotations in Freemarker reverse engineering templates?

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering, freemarker, hibernate-tools

I am trying to implement a FreeMarker custom reverse engineering template that automatically  creates my Hibernate classes. 
In the build process, the template is used by hibernate-tools to generate the hibernate classes. 
So far, I am using the default freemarker templates for that purpose and it works fine.

But now I am facing the questing: 
**How do I add additional properties to the default getter-annotations**?

The default freemarker method for One-to-may associations is (implemented in Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl):

```
...
<#elseif c2h.isCollection(property)>
    ${pojo.generateCollectionAnnotation(property, cfg)}
...
```

The generated java code is for example:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")      
public Set<ContactInformation> getContactInformations() {
    return this.contactInformations;
}
```

But I want to add **cascade = CascadeType.ALL** to each one-to-many getter annotation like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL
           fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
```

I am new to freemarker and hibernate and have no idea how to archive this.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is more simple: Just put **${property.setCascade("ALL")}** before **generateCollectionAnnotation** method call.

```
<#elseif c2h.isCollection(property)>
${property.setCascade("ALL")}
${pojo.generateCollectionAnnotation(property, cfg)}
```

Also the result is much better because it uses the javax.persistence.CascadeType enum.

```java
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
public Set<ContactInformation> getContactInformations() {
```

List of cascade types can be used:

```
${property.setCascade("persist, merge, delete, refresh")}
```

The result:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH }, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person") 
public Set<ContactInformation> getContactInformations() {
```

This solution also generate the cascade type for ManyToMany relation. You need to control that if you don't like this behavior. The @OneToMany orphanRemoval attribute can be generate, but is out of the scope of the question.

Kind regards.

Comment: I can't test this cause I don't work on this project anymore. But your answer looks more appropriate! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @Pascal. It works great, I am using it in a project.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the annotation

```
cascade = CascadeType.All
```

doesn't necessarily has to be in the signature of the @OneToMany-method.

The solution is to add the following line to the Freemarker template file Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl:

```
   @${pojo.importType("org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade")}(value=${pojo.importType("org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType")}.ALL)
```

All in all the method template for @OneToMany looks like this

```
<#elseif c2h.isCollection(property)>
   ${pojo.generateCollectionAnnotation(property, cfg)}
   @${pojo.importType("org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade")}(value=${pojo.importType("org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType")}.ALL)                    
<#else>
```

And a results would be f. i.:

```
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="person")
  @Cascade(value=CascadeType.ALL)                    
  public Set<ContactInformation> getContactInformations() {
       return this.contactInformations;
  }
```